# toggle opacity and reload div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a tabbed system on my page. Currently when clicked the opacity is toggled to show that div using:

```
$('.tabs').tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration: 'slow'} });
```

which is loaded in a javascript in the head of the page. I am trying to add an on-click event handler so that the div is also reloaded but it is having no effect, how can I get it to do both?

```
<div class="tabs">
         <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-0">Time Sheets</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Abscence Request</a></li>
         <li><a href="#tabs-2">Abscence Record</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="bordered_box">
        <div id="tabs-0"><?php include('timesheets.php'); ?></div>        
        <div id="tabs-1"><?php include('abscencerequestform.php'); ?></div></div>
        <div id="tabs-2"><?php include('abscencerecords.php'); ?></div>
        </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("a#tabs-0").on("click", function () {
            $("#tabs-0").load("timesheets.php");
        });
        $("a#tabs-1").on("click", function () {
            $("#atabs-1").load("abscencerequests.php");
        });
         $("a#tabs-2").on("click", function () {
            $("#atabs-2").load("abscencerecords.php");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: in the lower twoparts of the function, there are typos:  `a#tabs-1`instead of `#tabs-1`. also, do your php-files contain opening and closing <?php … ?> php brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have the tab content reloaded as you select each tab?

Just point your tabs directly to the PHP content, which will force load it each time the tab for a particular page is clicked.  JQuery will build the panels for you, so you only need this code below instead of the contents of `<div class="bordered_box">` :

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="timesheets.php">Time Sheets</a></li>
        <li><a href="abscencerequests.php">Abscence Request</a></li>
        <li><a href="abscencerecords.php">Abscence Record</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is just a simulated example, since I can't load active PHP scripts here:

```js
$(function() {
      
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs({ 
            fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration: 'slow'},
      activate: function(event ,ui){
          //console.log(event);
       alert("Simulating refreshed PHP content in Tab #" + ui.newTab.index());
              
   }
        });
         
                          
 });
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="timesheets.php">Time Sheets</a></li>
  <li><a href="abscencerequests.php">Abscence Request</a></li>
  <li><a href="abscencerecords.php">Abscence Record</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about PHP, but I do know that jQuery can chain methods, try this:

```
$('#tabs').tabs(function(event) { 
     fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration: 'slow'};
     $(this).find('a').bind('click', function(event) { 
            var link = $(this).attr('href');
                    $(window).load(link);
      });
      event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

I'm sure there's something that's not right...